# Problem with template creation in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates, new-project

I have a problem creating a project template in Visual Studio. I want to create a project template exactly like in the picture. Everything is exactly working there, everything starts. The template is created without problems, but when I create a new project using a ready-made template, I get something completely different from what I added when creating the template. It turns out that only the assembly that I specified as the main one (EasyPortalDev) remains, but everything else was lost somewhere. Tell me, please, what is the problem. Any hint would be very valuable.

This is what I want to get. Based on this I create a template -> [image]

This is what I get when I create a new project based on a new template -> [image]